# Binding to an Array in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am working on a WPF application. For some reason, the values in my view model are not showing

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
  private ObservableCollection<Item> items = Item.GetAll();
  public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
  {
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; }
  }
}

public class Item
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public List<int> Tally = new List<int>();

  public int Total { get; set; }

  public Item(int id)
  {
    this.ID = id;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
      this.Tally.Add(0);
  }

  public static ObservableCollection<Item> GetAll()
  {
    ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
      items.Add(new Item(i));
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

**MyPage.xaml**

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myGridView" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="ID" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Monday" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tally[0], Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Tuesday" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tally[1], Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Wednesday" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tally[2], Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Thursday" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tally[3], Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Friday" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tally[4], Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Total" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Total, Mode=OneWay}" />
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

An entry for each Item appears in the grid as expected. However, only the first and last columns have values. The values in the Monday-Friday columns (the columns that reference the Tally List) are not appearing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody please tell me?

Thank you!

Comment: Any binding error in the output window? Tried changing Tally to a property rather than a field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tally` is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), needs to be a public [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

*(I also hope that you are aware of [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if you want to make runtime changes)*

Answer (score 0):

ou're not using the Tally items anywhere in the observable collections either the local collection you return in the static method or the observable collection in the viewmodel.

Item should just be a Domain Type object(with a few auto getter and setter properties). You should create a service and call it **ItemsRepository** that would return **IEnumerable< Item >** collection when you call **GetAll()** on the repository.  Always try to avoid using anything Static if you can, especially a method that would return a collection.